# Following procedure gives error using call invoicetest.wj_get_invoicedatatest(1,:InvoicesCur ); call invoicetest.wj_get_invoice_cbodataidstest('X');

Tags: oracle

I have got error after using call for boyh procedures

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE invoicetest 
    IS
        TYPE InvoiceCBOIDCurs IS REF CURSOR;
        TYPE InvoicesCur IS REF CURSOR;

         PROCEDURE wj_get_invoice_cbodataidstest
    (
         InvoiceCBOIDs out InvoiceCBOIDCurs
    );
         PROCEDURE wj_get_invoicedatatest
    (
         Invoice out InvoicesCur,
         CBOID IN INTEGER
    );
    END invoicetest;
    /

    CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY invoicetest IS
    PROCEDURE wj_get_invoice_cbodataidstest
    (
         InvoiceCBOIDs out InvoiceCBOIDCurs
    )
    IS
    BEGIN
         OPEN InvoiceCBOIDs FOR
                 Select 1 from dual;
    END wj_get_invoice_cbodataidstest;

    PROCEDURE wj_get_invoicedatatest
    (
         Invoice out InvoicesCur,
         CBOID IN INTEGER
    )as
    begin
     OPEN Invoice FOR
     select cboid from dual;
    end wj_get_invoicedatatest;
    END invoicetest;
    /
```

Error after call:

> invoicetest.wj_get_invoicedatatest(1,:InvoicesCur ); call
>   invoicetest.wj_get_invoice_cbodataidstest('X');

Comment: What error? And how do you call the procedures? Please post the code with the procedure call and the error you are having

Comment: Error starting at line 43 in command:
call invoicetest.wj_get_invoicedatatest(1,:InvoicesCur )
Error report:
SQL Error: ORA-01008: not all variables bound
01008. 00000 -  "not all variables bound"
*Cause:    
*Action:

Comment: I have grant all privileges to user

Comment: You are calling the procedure with wrong arguments order; besides, the OUT parameter is a cursor, what do you need to do with it? You could better define a block with some variables to call your procedures

Comment: I also tried by function --function my_proc_test(CBOID IN NUMBER) RETURN sys_refcursor
 as
 InvoicesCur sys_refcursor;
 begin
 wj_get_invoicedatatest(CBOID,InvoicesCur);
 return InvoicesCur;

 end
 /
 
 SELECT my_proc_test(3) FROM DUAL;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your procedures are OK, but you are calling them in a wrong way; in one case you are using parameters in the wrong order, while in the other one you are passing a varchar while the procedure needs a cursor parameter.
This is a correct way to call your procedures:

```
SQL> declare
  2      vCurCBO invoicetest.InvoiceCBOIDCurs;
  3      vCur    invoicetest.InvoicesCur;
  4  begin
  5      invoicetest.wj_get_invoicedatatest(vCur, 1);
  6      --
  7      invoicetest.wj_get_invoice_cbodataidstest(vCurCBO);
  8      --
  9      /* what you need to do with your cursors */
 10  end;
 11  /

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```

To avoid confusion, you could pass parameters by explicitly using their names:

```
...
invoicetest.wj_get_invoicedatatest(
                                   Invoice       =>vCur,
                                   CBOID         => 1
                                  );
--
invoicetest.wj_get_invoice_cbodataidstest(
                                            InvoiceCBOIDs => vCurCBO
                                         );
...
```

If you need to use the CALL:

```
SQL> VARIABLE vCurCBO REFCURSOR;
SQL> VARIABLE vCur REFCURSOR;
SQL> CALL invoicetest.wj_get_invoice_cbodataidstest(
  2                                                  InvoiceCBOIDs => :vCurCBO
  3                                               );

Call completed.

SQL> CALL invoicetest.wj_get_invoicedatatest(
  2                                         Invoice       =>:vCur,
  3                                         CBOID         => 1
  4                                        );

Call completed.

SQL>
```

Comment: I want to use call package.procedure(arguments) format

Comment: I want output of this procedure in TIBCO BW Invoke adapter Palette

Comment: Thank You Aleksej.